# How should I texture objects in Blender to use in Unity?

Tags: unity, blender

I need to model some things to use in Unity. How should I texture objects (road, tree, etc.) in Blender?
I almost lost all textures when I exported and loaded them into Unity.

Answer (score 1):

1. Model your 3D art in Blender.
2. UV-map textures to your models in Blender.
3. Import the .blend files into Unity.
4. Import the textures into Unity (unless you prefer to include them in the .blend file).
5. Set the appropriate textures on the auto-imported materials.

That's about it.

Answer (score 0):

When you import a model from Blender(as .fbx or .obj ..etc), the textures will not be imported, but vertex colours will.

Textures and models are not linked when performing an import from certain file types. Save the textures separately and then import these textures into Unity. After you have your model and textures in Unity you can create a prefab with the model and texture by dragging the model into the scene and dragging the texture onto the model.

If the model is complex and comprised of several parts you can save several textures and apply them to individual parts of the model too.

Comment: I dont understand. At the same time, should also I import textures to Unity?

Comment: 1. import asset, that is ur model(.fbx) to unity 2. import asset thats is ur texture (png/jpg) 3. add texture to material of the model in unity